# how to specify a range in .htaccess file to redirect the url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

### i am trying to redirect url if ctatId is anything between 45 to 600. like below

`<pre>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} Delhi/(.*)/[45-600]
RewriteRule Delhi/(.*)/[45-600] pages/sub_category.php?city=Delhi&catId=$2
</pre>`

but problem is that it is also redirecting  URL  for `catiId  = 4` and every `catId` that starts with `4` like `41,42` etc
i think there is some thing wrong while specifying range

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a regular expression, that means you need something like:

```
(4[5-9]|[5-9][0-9]|[1-6][0-9][0-9])
```

That is:

- starts with 4, then 5-9
- or starts with 5-9 then another digit
- or starts with 1-6 then another 2 digits

So you just need:

```
RewriteRule Delhi/(.*)/(4[5-9]|[5-9][0-9]|[1-6][0-9][0-9]) pages/sub_category.php?city=Delhi&catId=$2
```

Comment: Or `(4[5-9]|[5-9][0-9]|[1-5][0-9]{2}|600)` without 601-699